# Solr SynonymGraphFilterFactory use analyzer defined in schema

Tags: java, solr

The SynonymGraphFilterFactory in Solr provides the possibility to specify an analyzer when parsing the synonyms file. I managed to run it specifying an in-build analyzer like `FrenchAnalyzer`.

```xml
<schema name="project" version="1.6">
  <fieldType name="text_synonyms" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" analyzer="org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr.FrenchAnalyzer"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldTypes>
</schema>
```

But now I need to provide an analyzer through the `schema.xml` file.
e.g.:

```xml
<schema name="project" version="1.6">
  <fieldType name="text_synonyms_parser" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      //custom tokenizer and filter
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="text_synonyms" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" analyzer="text_synonyms_parser"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldTypes>
</schema>
```

If I am doing it this way solr throws an exception at startup. Is it possible to specify an analyzer for the `SynonymGraphFilterFactory` which is defined in the `schema.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the analyzer option for the filter is looking for a class name.  In the second config, you have set it to a fieldType name, which probably doesn't work.